# Creating a gradient as a background for multiple images

Tags: android

I want to create a custom rating widget where the user can select the number of stars they want to rate an image as. I want to have each star become more blue as the rating is increased (example below). I'm planning on just making a custom image for each star, but I was wondering if there was a way to do this with a gradient drawable instead?

[image]